# Why does the protobuf use builder to construct data?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, builder

In java, to create a data structure we need to do like

```java
Builder builder=Data.newBuilder();
builder.setField(...);
...
Data=builder.build();
```

Why not just provoide the `getter()` and `setter()` for each field of `Data`?. like:

```
Data data=new Data();
data.setFiled(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Protobuf uses builders to generate Message objects, because [the message objects themselves are immutable](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#message):

> Message objects [...] are immutable, just like a Java String. To construct a message object, you need to use a builder.

This is *probably* done to allow optimizations that can only be done when Message objects are known not to change.

Comment: I don't know what the optimizations are. But one thing I can confirm is that it pays to convert from `Builder` to `Message` object.